# Attributing height data from points to Polylines for Tin creation?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, polygon, polyline-creation, tin

I have to make a TIN of water surface height from about 170 points which have been collected from RTK along a river. The points however are few and far between and rarely on the opposite banks to allow creation of triangles to create a decent TIN. This therefore produces a TIN with gaps. I should mention that i have created a polygon of the water area.

[image]

What i have been asked to do is create lines from one point (which has x,y,z data) to the other side of the river and connect it to the polygon (this does not contain x, y, z data). I then need to attribute the z value from the point to that line. This will then give me a water surface height. I have to do this to all the points and i cant figure out what to do apart from going through each value in excel and adding it manually.

[image]

So far, i have created a shapefile with polylines, and this is where i am stuck.

I don't understand how to use Python and my knowledge of ArcMap is relatively elementary.

Can you explain step-by-step how it can be done?

Comment: Spatial Join tool?

Comment: Hi @Hornbydd, i think you are right but i cant figure out what i need to do to get it to work. The help files are just a different language to me

Comment: Well at least you have looked at the help file! Puts you in the top 10% 